# Strange output in CPP for no apparent reason

Tags: c++

I am pretty well-versed in Python and Java, so I decided to try C++. I decided to make a Hangman game, but I am getting a very strange output when the first guess is wrong. If the first guess is right then every guess after that can be wrong and the program will run as it is supposed to.

Here is just some of the output when the first guess is wrong:

> Montserrat ? M S R ? M S ? English ( M m o n t s e r r a t ) ? ?! ╦' ? QL B! ? M a l t a ? M L T ? M T ? E n g l i s h ( M a l t a ) ? R s M a u r i t i u s ? M U S ? U ? M U R ? M a u r i t i a n R u p e e ? E n g l i s h ( M a u r i t i u s ) ? M K ? M a l a w i ? M W I ? M W ? M W K ? Malawian Kwacha ? E n g l i s h ( M a l a w i ) ? R M ! ï? ? φ2 K% ? ? ? ? ? E N M M a l a y s i a ? M Y S ? M Y R ? Malaysian R i n g g i t ? R i n g g i t M a l a y s i a ? H i j i r i C a l e n d a r ? Ö? Ö? :═ ? E n g l i s h ( M a l a y s i a ) ? M ? T ? W ? F ñC m═ p═ s 4 4 0 9 : 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 9 ? E n g l i s h ( N a m i b i a ) ? N o f o l k I s l a n d ? N F K ? N F ? E n g l i s h ( N o r f o l k I s l a n d ) ? E n g l i s h ( N i g e r i a ) N e t h e r l 0 8 0 9 : 0 0 0 2 0 4 0 9 ? N a u r u ? N R U ? N R ? E n g l i h ( N a u r u ) ? N i u e ? N I U ? N U ? E n g l i s h ( N i u e ) ? ╫╜ ┼╜ ? E N Z N e w Z e a l a n d ? N Z L ? N Z 1 4 0 9 : 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 9 ? P a p u a N e w G u i n e a ? P N G P G ? P G K ? P a p u a N e w G u i n e a n K i n a ? E n g l i s h ( P a p u a N e w G u i n e a ) ? ▒ ? E N P P h i l i p p i n e s ? P H L ? P H ? P H P ? P h i l i p p i n e P i s o 3 4 0 9 : 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 9 ? ?! ?! P a k i s t a n ? P A K ? K ? P K R ? P a k i s t a n i R u p e e ? E n g l i s h ( P a k i s t a n ) ? P p i t c a i r n Islands ? P C N ? P N ? English ( Pitcairn I s l a n d s ) P u e r t o R i c o P R I ? P R ? E n g l i s h ( P u e r t o R i c o ) ? P a l a u P L W ? P W ? E n g l i s h ( P a l a u ) ? R F ? R w a n d a R w a n d a n F r a n c ? E n g l i s h ( R w a n d a ) ? S o l m o n I s l a n d s ? S L B ? S B ? S B D ? S o l o m o n I s l a n d s D o l l a r ? E n g l i s h ( S o l o m o n I s l a n d s ) ? S R

I don't understand why this is being outputted when nothing like this is in the program.

I also get this message at the bottom of all the nonsense:

> Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

The code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

string guess();
string words = "Hangman";
char letter;
string blanks;
int lives = 3;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
    {
        blanks += "_";
    }
    cout << blanks;
    while(lives >= 1)
    {
        cout << endl << "Pick a letter\nLives: " << lives << endl;
        cin >> letter;
        system("CLS");
        cout << guess();
    }
}

string guess()
{
    int editCntr = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++)
    {
        if(words[i] == letter)
        {
            blanks[i] = words[i];
            editCntr++;
        }
    }
    if (editCntr > 0)
    {
        return blanks;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "The letter \"" << letter << "\" was not found." << endl;
        lives--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This function `string guess()` says it will return a string but it doesn't always do so. Since you're trying to print the returned value, and there isn't one, you get garbage. Try turning up the warning level on your compiler and pay attention to them.

Comment: Also, correct `\""` It means nothing and surely will mess the rest of the sentence.

Comment: @Ripi2 Looks like an escaped double-quote followed by a closing double-quote, to me.

Comment: @Ripi2 there is nothing wrong with the `\""`, it is being used correctly.

Comment: About `\""` you are right. I should have look slowly the full sentence before commenting. Sorry.

Comment: And an access violation means the program tried to use a resource (usually memory) that it doesn't own. This could be a result of the program trying to use a string that wasn't returned, but it could be a lot of different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"` means that an uncaught Access Violation exception is being thrown.

Your `guess()` function is declared as returning a `string`, but no `string` is being returned on a bad guess.  That is *Undefined Behavior*, which is why you are sometimes getting garbage printed, and sometimes getting a crash.

Change this:

```
cout << guess();
```

To this:

```
cout << guess() << endl;
```

And then change this:

```
cout << "The letter \"" << letter << "\" was not found." << endl;        
lives--;
```

To this:

```
lives--;
return "The letter \"" + string(1, letter) + "\" was not found.";
```